# How to style the option in the select input

Tags: html, css, forms, select

I'm looking to style the options within a `select` input and add some padding to enhance the appearance. Below is my current CSS and HTML setup, but I'm having trouble applying the padding to the options. What adjustments can I make to achieve this?

CSS:

```css
label {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Arial'; 
  display: inline;
}

select {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

option {
  /* How can I add padding to the options? */
}
```

HTML:

```html
<label for="fruits">Fruits</label>
<select name="fruits">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Mango</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>MuskMelon</option>
</select>
```

I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve the desired padding for the `option` elements. Thank you!

Comment: Not possible w/ CSS.

Comment: select elements do not really honor a lot of styling. Plenty of questions over the years on this. If you really want full control, you need to use JavaScript solution.

Comment: If you really need the select option then you should follow this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change much inside of an options menu like that. If you want to make a full customization dropdown menu then you have to make all the components yourself. I'm pretty sure you can only change the text in the option element but not the surroundings and if you can you probably have to use javascript not css

```css
/* Style The Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Fruit</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Apple</a>
    <a href="#">Mango</a>
    <a href="#">Banana</a>
    <a href="#">MuskMelon</a>
  </div>
</div>
```